# RewriteRule in DirectoryMatch for addresses without extension

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I want it so that all URL requests without a ".php" extension are handled by the appropriate .php file, and still be able to name those files with the ".php" extension.

```
<DirectoryMatch "/var/www/html">   #This works for the one directory
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^(\w+)$" "$1.php"
</DirectoryMatch>
```

This is what should work for all subdirectories:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^(/var/www/htm).*">    #This does not work
```

Here's a list of things I've tried that I thought should all be the same but aren't:

```
<DirectoryMatch "/var/www/html">     #this works
<DirectoryMatch /var/www/html>       #this works 
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html">    #"The requested URL was not found on this server."
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html$">   #"The requested URL was not found on this server."
<DirectoryMatch "^(/var/www/html)$"> #"The requested URL was not found on this server."
<DirectoryMatch "^(/var/www/htm).*"> #"The requested URL was not found on this server."
```

It seems as soon as I actually use regular expressions, it no longer works.  However, the regular expression in the rewrite rule does work.

Why isn't the regex working for DirectoryMatch?

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to do is write a separate entry for each directory:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/test">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^(\w+)$" "$1.php"
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/dashboard">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^(\w+)$" "$1.php"
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/dashboard/wizard">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^(\w+)$" "$1.php"
</Directory>
```